# spring boot gcp firestore Issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

getting issue after adding the dependency in to gradle

dependency added

```
//Firestore
    implementation('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-data-firestore:1.2.8.RELEASE')
```

i haven't done any configuration when i just running the application i am getting the below error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on com.google.cloud.spring.autoconfigure.firestore.GcpFirestoreAutoConfiguration$FirestoreReactiveAutoConfiguration.firestoreMappingContext
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[spring-context-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:193) ~[spring-context-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:153) ~[spring-context-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:129) ~[spring-context-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:343) ~[spring-context-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247) ~[spring-context-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112) ~[spring-context-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:748) ~[spring-context-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[spring-context-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731) ~[spring-boot-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at com.ford.pro.fleetmanagement.fleetiointegration.FleetioIntegrationApplication.main(FleetioIntegrationApplication.java:32) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: @ConditionalOnMissingBean did not specify a bean using type, name or annotation and the attempt to deduce the bean's type failed
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$Spec.validate(OnBeanCondition.java:490) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$Spec.<init>(OnBeanCondition.java:439) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:155) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanTypeDeductionException: Failed to deduce bean type for com.google.cloud.spring.autoconfigure.firestore.GcpFirestoreAutoConfiguration$FirestoreReactiveAutoConfiguration.firestoreMappingContext
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$Spec.deducedBeanTypeForBeanMethod(OnBeanCondition.java:520) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$Spec.deducedBeanType(OnBeanCondition.java:509) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$Spec.<init>(OnBeanCondition.java:432) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.cloud.spring.data.firestore.mapping.FirestoreMappingContext
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.FilteringSpringBootCondition.resolve(FilteringSpringBootCondition.java:108) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$Spec.getReturnType(OnBeanCondition.java:528) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$Spec.deducedBeanTypeForBeanMethod(OnBeanCondition.java:516) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    ... 21 common frames omitted

2024-02-08 11:43:58.159  WARN [fleetio-integration-and-global-preferences,,] 77110 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Unable to close ApplicationContext

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.google.cloud.spring.autoconfigure.firestore.GcpFirestoreAutoConfiguration$FirestoreReactiveAutoConfiguration] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@531d72ca]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:485) ~[spring-core-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:361) ~[spring-core-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:418) ~[spring-core-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$2(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:765) ~[spring-beans-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1708) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:764) ~[spring-beans-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:703) ~[spring-beans-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:674) ~[spring-beans-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1684) ~[spring-beans-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:570) ~[spring-beans-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:669) ~[spring-beans-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:661) ~[spring-beans-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1302) ~[spring-context-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromMappedException(SpringApplication.java:864) ~[spring-boot-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromException(SpringApplication.java:852) ~[spring-boot-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleExitCode(SpringApplication.java:839) ~[spring-boot-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:779) ~[spring-boot-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:317) ~[spring-boot-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at com.ford.pro.fleetmanagement.fleetiointegration.FleetioIntegrationApplication.main(FleetioIntegrationApplication.java:32) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/cloud/spring/data/firestore/mapping/FirestoreClassMapper
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3402) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2504) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:467) ~[spring-core-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.cloud.spring.data.firestore.mapping.FirestoreClassMapper
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
    ... 25 common frames omitted


> Task :FleetioIntegrationApplication.main() FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
```

1. i changed the spring boot versions
2. changed the dependency
3. I checked any other configuration related to firestore in service but nothing is there